# Is it possible to inject header in FullCalendar version6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

In version 6 of full calendar there is a possibility to inject a content via ng-template. Example is based on eventContent.

```
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions">
  <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
    <b>{{ arg.event.title }}</b>
  </ng-template>
</full-calendar>
```

Is it also possible for a header? I couldn't find an information about it. I tried with #header and #headerToolbar but it's not really working.

Comment: There is no content injection hook for the header at the moment. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/toolbar shows what you can do to set the content options - it is much more limited, you don't have any real freedom unfortunately. Read https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features if you want to request such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize all the following parts:

```
["dayHeaderContent", "dayCellContent", 
"weekNumberContent", "nowIndicatorContent", 
"eventContent", "slotLaneContent", 
"slotLabelContent", "allDayContent", 
"moreLinkContent", "noEventsContent", 
"resourceAreaHeaderContent", "resourceGroupLabelContent", 
"resourceLabelContent", "resourceLaneContent", 
"resourceGroupLaneContent"]
```

It doesn't seem that the HEADER is a part of it.